# Adding only a single instance of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addclass

I'm trying to add a class to an element using jQuery. If the user clicks on an element it adds a class, which I can do, but I want only 1 instance of that class to be active so if the user clicks on something else that class is then removed from the previous element and added to the current one.

https://jsfiddle.net/gsuxjce2/3/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.col {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.added {
  background-color: blue;
}

 $('.box').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('added');

    if ( $(this).hasClass('added'); ) {
                    $(this).removeClass('added');
    } else {
            $(this).toggleClass('added');
    }

 });
```

Comment: `$('.foo').removeClass('foo')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.added').removeClass('added');`

inside your click event before everything.

Comment: Thanks - this is the one I saw first and tried even though j08691 answered the same as well

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `.added` class from all `.box` elements first, then just add it to the one clicked on with `this`:

```
 $('.box').click(function() {
     $('.box').removeClass('added');
     $(this).addClass('added');
 });
```

```js
 $('.box').click(function() {
   $('.box').removeClass('added');
   $(this).addClass('added');
 });
```

```css
.col {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.added {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Love how simple this is! Is it the 'this' that's stopping all the other ones from also adding the class?

Comment: The `this` above refers to the `.box` element being clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to the start of you `click` event:

```
jQuery(".added").each(function(i,el){
    jQuery(el).removeClass("added")
});
```

This removes all instances of the class, so that when you add one new, then that will be unique.

Comment: Any particular reason you included `.each`?

Comment: What does the i, el do?

Comment: To **lejimmie**: `i` is the current index in the array of elements that contain the class `added` and `el` is  the current element. The `el` is simply a reference to an of the HTML element that contain the class. To **James Thorpe**: I was going for the most versatile solution, since that would be easiest for a green developer to extend from. **Rodrigo Graça**'s solution though is more professional and a lot nicer to look at.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Noted :)